# Exempting a row from a group of items by MIN function group by a column

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to exempt a Party where vote is not MAX i.e.

## ID  |   Party        |  Year    |   Constituency    |   Votes

1   |   Labour       |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   19063

2   |   Plaid Cymru  |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   2955

3   |   Liberal Democrat |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   2933

4   |   Conservative     |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   2296

5   |   Independent  |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   1960

6   |   Independent  |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   727

7   |   Independent  |  2001    |   Aberavon    |   256

18  |   Liberal Democrat |  2001    |   Aberdeenshire   |   16507

19  |   Conservative     |  2001    |   Aberdeenshire   |   11686

20  |   Labour       |  2001    |   Aberdeenshire   |   4669

21  |   Independent  |  2001    |   Aberdeenshire   |   4634

22  |   Independent  |  2001    |   Aberdeenshire   |   418

55  |   Independent  |  2001    |   Angus       |   12347

56  |   Conservative     |  2001    |   Angus       |   8736

57  |   Labour       |  2001    |   Angus       |   8183

58  |   Liberal Democrat |  2001    |   Angus       |   5015

59  |   Independent  |  2001    |   Angus       |   732

2053    |   Plaid Cymru  |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   3545

2054    |   Labour       |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   18077

2055    |   Green        |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   510

2056    |   Conservative     |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   3064

2057    |   Liberal Democrat |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   4140

2058    |   Veritas      |  2005    |   Aberavon    |   768

2075    |   SNP      |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   5484

2076    |   Scottish Social  |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   706

2077    |   Conservative     |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   3271

2078    |   Labour       |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   19568

2079    |   Scottish Indepen |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   337

2080    |   Liberal Democrat |  2005    |   Airdrie     |   3792

2087    |   UK Independence  |  2005    |   Aldridge        |   1093

2088    |   Labour       |  2005    |   Aldridge        |   13237

2089    |   Conservative     |  2005    |   Aldridge        |   18744

2090    |   Liberal Democrat |  2005    |   Aldridge        |   4862

2091    |   British National |  2005    |   Aldridge        |   1620

4575    |   UK Independence  |  2010    |   Bolsover    |   1721

4576    |   Liberal Democrat |  2010    |   Bolsover    |   6821

4577    |   British National |  2010    |   Bolsover    |   2640

4578    |   Conservative     |  2010    |   Bolsover    |   10812

4579    |   Labour       |  2010    |   Bolsover    |   21994

6953    |   British National |  2010    |   Yeovil          |   1162

6954    |   Conservative     |  2010    |   Yeovil      |   18807

6955    |   Liberal Democrat |  2010    |   Yeovil      |   31843

6956    |   UK Independence  |  2010    |   Yeovil      |   2357

6957    |   Labour       |  2010    |   Yeovil      |   2991

In the above table, I would like a query to exempt say, Labour, Independent, Liberal Democrat, and Conservative where they do not have the highest votes in a particular Constituency and certain ElectionYear.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you reduce this to just a few rows of data and reformat it so it is easier to read? It is hard to know what you are asking with your data in this format.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: It's now re-formatted for readability

Comment: Ok, looks much better now. What kind of output would you like to receive?

Comment: I would like a query to exempt say, Labour, Independent, Liberal Democrat, and Conservative where they do not have the highest votes in a particular Constituency and certain ElectionYear

Comment: So are you looking for YEAR--PARTY WITH HIGHEST VOTES--NUMBER OF VOTES?

Comment: To be fairly clear on what I want for the output. For example, in 2001, Labour as a party had the highest votes in Constituency named Aberavon. I would like the query to populate only Party, Election Year, Constituency and Vote where Labour, Independent, Liberal Democrat, and Conservative does not have the highest votes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT theyear
        , constituency
        , party
        , MAX(votes) AS votes
   FROM   thetable
   GROUP BY theyear, party, constituency
   )
 WHERE party NOT IN ('Labour', 'Independent', 'Liberal Democrat', 'Conservative')
```

Comment: Well done, thanks for giving it a try but the query is not giving me the output I desire. Like I once said, I would like a query to exempt say, Labour, Independent, Liberal Democrat, and Conservative where they do not have the highest votes in a particular Constituency and certain ElectionYear. Meanwhile, where the above mentioned parties had low votes should be populated by the query. Thank you.

Comment: If you can check the sample data posted; you'll find out that in _Aberavon- constituency  in 2001, Labour has the highest votes for that constituency. I want where say for instance, Labour has one the of the minimum votes in a constituency.

Comment: I think I'm going to bow out now and give someone else an opportunity to help you, because I still can't tell what you're looking for.